# Where is the Riot keybackup stored? (Chat Riot/Matix/Synapse)

Tags: linux, matrix

We have configured a Matrix-Synapse homeserver.
In Riot-Chat you can store all your encryption keys in a central backup:
[image: S]

**Question**: Where is this backup stored?
On the homeserver? On the federation server? On the vector.im-Server?
... and (where) can I configure this (in the homeserver.yml)?

If I overlooked this information while searching the web, I would be thankfull for a link.

Comment: What do you mean by "federation server"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encrypted keys are backed up (encrypted) on the home server: https://github.com/uhoreg/matrix-doc/blob/e2e_backup/proposals/1219-storing-megolm-keys-serverside.md